# strange behaviour spring security session concurrency

Tags: spring-security, login-control

i find that spring security, session concurrency is very strange.

```
<sec:session-management>
        <sec:concurrency-control max-sessions="1" error-if-maximum-exceeded="true" />
</sec:session-management>
```

the code means that, just only one user can log in in time.

1. i successfully login, than hit logout button. log out is successfully (i don't get my username anymore). but when i try to relogin, i just get exception that maximum session exceeded. is session in spring security is not deleted clearly?
2. i finish login. and i with out log out, i try to login again. i still can login. but when the second time i to relogin, i get exception that maximum session exceeded. i think it should be rejected to login when first time try to relogin.

thanks for your response
Best regards

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Make sure you didn't forget to configure a listener in `web.xml`, as required for session management:

```
<listener>
    <listener-class>
        org.springframework.security.web.session.HttpSessionEventPublisher
    </listener-class>
</listener>
```

Answer (score 1):

I guess spring security has not been told to invalidate the current session on logout.  This can be done by `<logout>` element as documented [here](http://static.springsource.org/spring-security/site/docs/3.0.x/reference/appendix-namespace.html#nsa-logout)

Answer (score 0):

I think Raghuram is right.

You try following:

```
<logout invalidate-session="true" logout-url="/logout.htm"
logout-success-url="/login.jsp?loggedout=true" />
```

Here I am invalidating session on logout and redirecting user to login page.
Hope this is helpful. If this is not the case then let me know.